# AES pads byte array with \0 when decrypting

Tags: c#, string, aes

Whenever I decrypt a file I end up with \0 in between each character (this is a text file) The original is fine, and the decryption is successful without errors.

When I do open the file ; "hello" would become "h\0e\0l\0..."

Here is my decryption function: (I came up with a fix of converting the byte array to utf8 then manually removing the nulls, this is obviously not a solution. )

```
public static void DecryptFileToFile(String fromFile, String toFile, byte[] Key)
{
    byte[] encryptedFile = IO.convertFileToByte(fromFile);

    using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
    {
        byte[] dataIV = encryptedFile.Take(16).ToArray(); //first 16 bytes is iv
        byte[] encryptedData = encryptedFile.Skip(16).Take(encryptedFile.Length-16).ToArray();
        aesAlg.Key = Key;
        using (var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(Key, dataIV))
        {
            byte[] final =  PerformCryptography(decryptor, encryptedData);
            string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(final);
            result = result.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
            IO.writeStringToFile(result,toFile);
        }
    }
}
private static byte[] PerformCryptography(ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform, byte[] data)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, cryptoTransform, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

to encrypt:

```
public static void EncryptFileToFile(String fromFile, String toFile, byte[] Key){

            byte[] original = IO.convertFileToByte(fromFile);

            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.GenerateIV();
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                using (var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(Key, aesAlg.IV))
                {
                    byte[] encryptedData =  PerformCryptography(encryptor, original);
                    byte[] final = Combine(aesAlg.IV,encryptedData);
                    IO.writeByteToFile(final, toFile);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You've tagged this `java` and `android`, but this looks like C# to me... please clarify.

Comment: Thank you, its hard when switching between languages daily.

Comment: Next, I note that you haven't provided the *encryption* code which presumably converts a string to a byte array to start with. My guess is that that doesn't use UTF-8. If you could provide a [mcve] it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I agree.  The issue is with the encryption method.  The byte[] data didn't use UTF8 encoding.  A string is a two byte object with a private property which indicates if each character is one or two bytes.  When you convert a string to a byte[] and use Unicode Encoding it adds a zero in the MSB when the original character was ascii 0-255.

Comment: I have added the encryption function to the question also.

Comment: IO.writebytetofile == File.writeallbytes.

Comment: EncryptFileToFile function is encrypting a file. What encoding is the contents of the file in?

Comment: It could be any type. Not all text files come from a single machine.

Comment: Is it possible then that you have encrypted a UTF-16 file and then assumed it was UTF-8 when decrypting it?

Comment: @MartinBrown More likely an in memory string, as the default for strings is UTF-16LE for .NET.